# Very long response times in Android browser when retrieving Firebase data

Tags: android, firebase, android-browser

We are building iOS and Android apps using Cordova to be able to have a single code base and also deploy the apps as websites. We use Firebase for data.

Our apps work well on both iOS and Android and also on most browsers, but when retrieving Firebase data from the Android browser it takes long time for the data to load (up to 20 seconds). If we instead runt Chrome on the Android device the data retrieval is very quick.

I'm sorry if there is details missing in the description of the problem, but in short Firebase data retrieval is very slow when we run the Android browser on an Android device.

Any hints/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: Some  code would be appreciated. Ideally both times should be the same and only depend on your network but there may be something in the way you have written the code which could change that

Comment: getTipsStatistik: function(onSuccess){
  var ref = new Firebase(ENV.firebaseUrl).child('tipsStatistic');
  ref.once('value', function(data){
    if(data.val() !== null){
      onSuccess(data.val());
    }
  });
}

Comment: $scope.getTipsStatistik = function(){
 getTravinfo.getTipsStatistik(function(data){
  $scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.form = data;
  });
 });
};

Comment: The two code snippets above are what we are using.

Comment: At every call to Firebase we create a new Firebase reference, not sure if that is in line with best practices or not.

Comment: We have found a couple of mobile devices where the response times are not that long. Wonder if there could be some setting that affects the communication with Firebase, e.g. security related or something else.

Comment: I realize that the above information might not be enough, but we are struggling with how to debug the issue.